# How to get JNI signatures for Android classes

Tags: java, android

Given that I have the Android SDK installed (Linux), how do I get the method signatures for the `android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech` class? I know it has something to do with `javap` but darn if I can get it to work.

Comment: You use `javap -s` and use what follows 'descriptor'. NB "cant get it to work" is not a problem description.

Comment: Fair enough: For the record I tried `javap -s -p android.speech.tss.TextToSpeech` but it reported it couldn't find the class. I have the android and java SDK's installed. Not sure what else I need.

Comment: The signature I need is for the constructor `TextToSpeech(Context context, TextToSpeech.OnInitListener listener)`

Comment: Your `javap` was looking at the JDK classes, not the Android classes. Come to think of it, it won't work on Android classes unless they use the same .class file format.

Comment: OK, I'm new to all this JNI, NDK stuff. I'm using Go lang, so this C and JNI stuff is challenging me. I thought I understood enough to ask the right question. Obviously, I have some work to do on my understanding. Thanks to everyone for their patience.

Answer (score 0):

OK,after some more education, this is what I came up with:

```
jmethodID midInit = (*env)->GetMethodID(
    env, 
    cls, 
    "<init>",
 (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/speech/tts/TextToSpeech$OnInitListener;)V);
```

The last param is the signature I was asking about.

Answer (score -1):

You look them up online in the android documentation at https://developer.android.com/.  That has all the documentation for all the classes and functions in Android.  That has nothing to do with JNI though, unless you were trying to ask something else and just didn't word it well.

Comment: Yeah, I probably didn't word it well. I want to call an Android method from C using JNI. My understanding is that I need to pass a signature string to the `JNI.CallObjectMethod()`.

Comment: The signature is always the same as the Java signature.  Use the conversion table from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html.

Comment: @GabeSechan Your comment doesn't make sense. If the signatures are the same (they aren't), how can there be a conversion table?

Comment: They are the same.  The conversion table is how you convert from the Java types to the string.  For example, ints are Z, shorts are S, etc.  So the signature string for long f (int n, String s, int[] arr); is (ILjava/lang/String;[I)J .  The int converts to Z, the String is a class, and the int arrar is [Z].  The return is J for long.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I said Z was int.  I was thinking math, where Z is the set of all integers.  Here Z is Boolean, I is int.

Comment: That still doesn't make sense. The Java signature has to be converted to the JNI signature via the tables. As in your own examples. The Java signature is `long f(int n, String s, int[] arr)` and the JNI signature is `(ILjava/lang/String;[I)J`. These are not the same.

Comment: They are the same.  I means Integer.  J means long.  L means a class, with the class name coming after it.  [] means array.  The signatures are the exact same, you just use that notation instead of writing it out longhand.  That's also the same notation the JRE uses internally to the interpreter.